Is it better to have a wide range of IPs or a small range of IPs on the router configuration?
Is it better to have a wide range of IPs or a small range of IPs on the router configuration?
In my network, I have about 350 devices.
My IP range is right now 192.168.1.1/24 -> 192.168.1.255.
I have several routers (mode is router, not bridge) with some devices connected.
Is it better to put all routers in bridge mode only and to set a range 192.168.0.1/23 -> 192.168.1.255?
The reason is that I want to manage all devices in the network directly on my FortiGate 40F Firewall.

Better for what? The word "better" is generally related to opinion unless you have clearly define your circumstances and requirements in such a way that we can empirically state one option is better able to satisfy your needs than another. But you haven't given us this information, so we don't know what it is that you hope it is "better" than.

The real issue isn't the subnet size, it's the problems caused by doing double NAT.
It's best to avoid double NAT unless you really know what you're doing and have a good justification that outweighs the downsides of double NAT.
So have the device at the head of your network be the NAT and DHCP server for your entire network, and have your additional APs act as pure APs, so they transparently bridge traffic from wireless clients to the wired LAN (no NAT).
Making your NAT private subnet a /23 instead of a /24 is perfectly fine. The marginal increase of load on your NAT gateway device should be fairly negligible.
